# Xcode unit test shows 'No such module <project name>' but it can run?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I create an application with multiple build config, bundle id, and product name. I can run the unit test but in the unit test code, there is an error shows *No such module 'ProjectName'* like in the picture below. Still, it can run the unit test and the test is passed as well. It can't use the auto complete, though.

**I have cleaned the build folder and restart the Xcode but it's not work.**

[image: It shows No such module 'ProjectName' but it still can run]

I don't know what's going on. Could someone give me some workaround?

**Update**
I found the solution. Just change the build scheme in `Use [build scheme] for command-line builds` to your unit test build scheme test target at the project level on info tab. Then everything works fine.

Comment: A few ideas for you... build your project first before running the unit tests, check that the name of the project/module is correct, make sure that the test file your working on is part of the test target, you could also try clearing your derived data folder

Answer (score 0):

just try to clean and restart Xcode it will work properly

Comment: I tried to clean and restart it for many times but I have no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete derived data https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-derived-data-xcode/
2. Clean the project with cmd + k
3. Build and re-run the unit tests with cmd + u

Comment: Don't work, the error message still show but Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just change the build scheme in `Use [build scheme] for command-line builds` to your unit test build scheme test target at the project level on info tab. Then everything works fine.